# a positive matrix of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $F$ be a complex Hilbert space. Let $A,B,C,D\in \mathcal{B}(F)$. Consider the operator matrix $T$ such that
\begin{equation*}
T=\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

> I see in a paper that $T$ is a positive operator on $F\oplus F$ if and only if $\langle Tx,x \rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F\oplus F$. But I don't understand how to calculate $\langle Tx,x \rangle$. What is the inner product on $F\oplus F$? Is $F\oplus F$ the direct sum of $F$ and $F$ or the tensor product of of $F$ and $F$?

Thank you.

Comment: $F\oplus F$ is the direct sum, not the tensor-product. Let $x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix}\in F\oplus F$, similar $x'=\begin{pmatrix} x_1'\\ x_2'\end{pmatrix}$. Then
$$\langle x, x'\rangle_{F^2}=\langle x_1,x_1'\rangle_F + \langle x_2,x_2'\rangle_F.$$

Comment: Thank you. If $F\oplus F=F^2$?

Comment: I mean what is the difference between direct sum and cartesian product ?

Comment: @Thierry Strictly speaking, the Cartesian product of Hilbert spaces doesn't come with an inner product.  However, cartesian products and direct sums of finite collections indeed result in the same underlying sets.

Comment: @Thierry also, tensor products use $\otimes$ rather than $\oplus$.

Comment: Yes I mean $F^2= F\oplus F$. The difference between direct sum and cartesian product is that the direct sum is a [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) and the cartesian product is a [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct). The category of Hilbert spaces doesn't have a coproduct, but it has a product. The category of vector spaces (without any additional structure) has both, and they differ only if you are looking at infinite products.

Comment: @s.harp Thank you. Could you please convert your comments as an answer because it is very helpful and thank you.

Comment: sure, but just a remark: I confused the coproduct with the product again. Direct product of vector sapces is a coproduct not a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $F\oplus F$ refers to the direct product of the Hilbert spaces $F$ and $F$. This is not the same as the tensor product, which is written $F\otimes F$. The scalar product on $F\oplus F$ is defined as follows:

If $x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix}\in F\oplus F$ with $x_1,x_2\in F$, and $x'=\begin{pmatrix}x_1'\\ x_2'\end{pmatrix}$ similarly, then
$$\langle x,x'\rangle_{F\oplus F}:= \langle x_1,x_1'\rangle_F +\langle x_2,x_2'\rangle.$$

This will give you an inner product on the vectorspace $F\oplus F$. One can verify that $F\oplus F$ is complete with this inner product, this follows out of $\|x\|^2_{F\oplus F}=\|x_1\|_F^2+\|x_2\|^2_F$. Specifically if $x^{(n)}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $F\oplus F$, we find that the components $x_1^{(n)}$, $x_2^{(n)}$ must also be Cauchy in $F$. Since $F$ is a Hilbert space these two sequences admit limits $x_1,x_2$. Let $x$ be the vector having these as components. Then:
$$\|x^{(n)}-x\|^2_{F\oplus F}=\|x_1^{(n)}-x_1\|^2_F + \|x_2^{(n)}-x_2\|^2_F.$$
Both terms on the right hand side converge to zero so $x^{(n)}\to x$ in $F\oplus F$ and thus every Cauchy sequence converges.